# Resolve Array<Promise> after updating a field in array of objects using some matcher

Tags: typescript

I have a array of objects and the matcher that should update all objects field with value in matcher but the result is array of promises instead of Array of Objects

This is typescript. 
I have tried the following code but it returns Array of Promises after return is reached

The following code is just an example with my real code simplified, so I don't need and transformation from numbers to strings :)

```
async updateColumn(data: Array<any>, matcher: Array<string>): Promise<Array<any>> {
        let fieldName="hour";
        return data.map((item) => {
            const value =item[fieldName];
            item[fieldName] = matcher[value];
            return item;
        });
    }
```

Array of objects is like

```
data=[{
id="1159",
hour = "11",
minute = "53"
},
{
id="1256",
hour = "13",
minute = "54"
}]
```

JSON matcher is like

```
matcher={
    "11": "Eleven",
    "13: "Thirteen"
}
```

I expect to get something like

```
data=[{
id="1256",
hour = "Eleven",
minute = "53"
},
{
id="1256",
hour = "Thirteen",
minute = "54"
}]
```

in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here promise is not what you need.

In updateColumn function you return an Array not a Promise.

Promise is made to wait for a response (http, child-process, events ...), here you just run synchronous code, so your function is not asynchronous.

Note: async keyword has to be used with await, the only object you can await in JavaScript (and sublanguage) are Promise.

Answer (score 0):

An async function returns a promise. Returning a value from it resolves the promise. Hence you need to call `then` onto it to grab the data -> `updateColumn(data, matcher).then(data => )`.